# JS type conversion between string and number

Tags: javascript, string, type-conversion

I'm puzzled with the type convert in javascript .

```
var temp = "111"
temp = temp + 0 // temp is "1110" now 
temp = temp - 0 // temp is number , 111 

temp = "1110" - 0 // temp is number 1110
```

I'm curious what causes such differences in two ways .

Sorry , I forgot the assignment led to abnormal results .

Comment: This is because string concatenation in javascript is done with the plus sign, and of course you can't subtract a string from a string, so there is no equivalent for the minus sign, so when you think about it, it makes perfect sense.

Comment: temp = temp - 0 // temp is number , 111 
is not correct. you will get 1110

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it seems to be based on an observation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that

```
temp = temp - 0 // temp is number , 111
```

yields the result you mentioned there. See http://jsbin.com/faquvobo/1/edit?js,output

You have an observation error (maybe you actually used `temp = 0 + temp;`).

---

General explanation:

The `+` operator is overloaded and the `-` operator isn't.

If you use the `+` operator and one operand is a string, the operand is converted to a string and string concatenation is performed (instead of addition).

The `-` operator is only defined for numbers, so both operands are converted to numbers first and subtraction is performed.

Comment: You are right, in fact, that I forgot the assignment led to abnormal results, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

in javascript, the `+` operator performs typecasting to string if either of the operands is not a number, while the  `-` operator always casts to number.

so your code will look like this after typecasting:

```
var temp = "111";

//before cast and variable evaluation
var temp2 = temp + 0;
//after cast and variable evaluation
var temp2 = "111" + "0"; // evaluates to string "1110" => string concatenate
//temp2 is string "1110"
//before cast and variable evaluation
temp2 = temp2 - 0;
//after cast and variable evaluation
temp2 = 1110 - 0; //evaluates to number 1110 => number subtraction
//temp2 is number 1110

//before cast and variable evaluation
var temp3 = "1110" - 0;
//after cast and variable evaluation
var temp3 = 1110 - 0; // evaluates to number 1110 => number subtraction
//temp3 is number 1110
```

Answer (score 0):

From [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1).  For  [Addition operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1):

> 7.If Type(lprim) is String or Type(rprim) is String, then Return the
> String that is the result of concatenating ToString(lprim) followed by
> ToString(rprim)
>
> 8.Return the result of applying the addition operation to ToNumber(lprim) and ToNumber(rprim).

This means `+` operator will try String firstly if one of them is String. Otherwise, it will apply number addition by converting them into number.

For [Subtraction Operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.2) :

> 5.Let lnum be ToNumber(lval).
>
> 6.Let rnum be ToNumber(rval).
>
> 7.Return the result of applying the subtraction operation to lnum and rnum

It means `-` operator will always convert to number and apply number subtraction operation.